# How to change the menu background color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

[image: I want to change this color to be #ff0] 
when i search in `style.css` I found this

```
.menu-primary li a:hover, .menu-primary li a:active, .menu-primary li a:focus, 
.menu-primary li:hover > a, .menu-primary li.current-cat > a, .menu-primary li.current_page_item > a, .menu-primary li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #DD363D;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DE4349;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

and the value of background is 
`.menu-primary li li a:hover, .menu-primary li li a:active, .menu-primary li li a:focus, 
.menu-primary li li:hover > a, .menu-primary li li.current-cat > a, .menu-primary li li.current_page_item > a, .menu-primary li li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #DD2F35;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;`

when i change the color value didn't affect ?
the un visited hover link and menu background have the same color ?
how to change it ?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak i change them with the color value but didn't affect !!!

Comment: link us to your site

Comment: @indubitablee  work with localhost !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color: #000` = The color of the font.

`background-color: #000` = The color of that element's background.

Comment: I didn't understand what you just typed.

Comment: when i change the value of background color didn't affect !

Comment: Edit your question to show your current progress. Also, linking to what you're describing and providing a snippet on this question would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
.menu-primary{
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

What you have previously worked on the color of the text, not the background.
The code above changes the background color of the menu class.

Comment: don't affect with the `background-color`

Comment: Try to add !important after the #000000.

Comment: also didn't affect ! and i edit my question with picture can help to understand me 1